# Favicon.ico works locally, but not on test-server

Tags: webpack, aurelia, favicon

I do have a issue when trying to set the favicon.ico on my test server, locally everything works fine..
To reach my test-server i use the following URL:

http://app-server/company/companyproject%20test/client/

I have the following project structure and I am using webpack.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7irMH.png)

Does somebody have any idea how this works?

If u need more information, feel free to comment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to visit the file directly in browser (_by typing the file url in browser_)

Comment: Thank u for the comment. I went to visit the file at http://app-server/company/companyproject%20test/client/favicon.ico. This shows the favicon for me. However, somehow in my website, it is not showing the favicon.

Comment: You don't see favicon or see wrong/old one?

Comment: If I navigate to http://app-server/company/companyproject%20test/client/favicon.ico it shows the expected favicon. However, if I navigate to my project, it does not show my favicon. It shows that default icon (like it can not find my favicon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the favicon is simply not available in the `dist` folder once your app is built.
Try copying it to the `dist` folder using `copy-webpack-plugin` (`npm i --save-dev copy-webpack-plugin`)

Import it in your `webpack.config.js` as

`const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin")`

and finally add it to `plugins` as below

`new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "favicon.ico", to: "favicon.ico" }])`

Personally, i would mainain such assets in a folder and copy over the entire folder to the build folder (`dist`) to prevent having to copy individual files.

`new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "icons", to: "icons" }])`

thereby making it possible to do

`<link rel="icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico">`

`<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/icons/apple-icon-180x180.png">`

in your `index.ejs`

Comment: Hello. Sorry for my late reaction. I've just tried the code. Now I still get a 404 not found on the icon. That is because it is looking in http://app-server/icons/favicon.ico. However, my favicon is at http://app-server/company/assignment%20test/client/icons/favicon.ico.

Comment: It is working now, I've got my favicon in the assets folder and then I used the following link: <link rel="icon" href="/company/assignment%20test/client2/assets/images/favicon/favicon.ico">